# Require child classes to call super.doSomething() if overrides it?

Tags: c#, java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a abstract class named Vehicle:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

    public void run() {
        addToRunningVehicleList();
    }

}
```

I want that every classes that `extends` Vehicle must call `super.run()` if they `override` `run` method. For example:

```
public class Car {

    @Override
    public void run() { // Error here because does not call super.run()
        carRunningAnimation();
    }

}
```

Is it possible in OOP concept, or Java/C#?

**EDIT:** Following Petar Ivanov, I have this code:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

    public final void run() {
        Log.e("Run", "Add To List");
        runImp();
    }

    public void runImp() {}

}

public class Car extends Vehicle {

    @Override
    public void runImp() {
        Log.e("Run", "Run in Car");
    }

}
```

However, it's not very good for public APIs. When extending Vehicle, the end-users must override `runImp`, but then they have to call `run()` method, so I have to make public both `run` and `runImp`, which make nothing better.

Comment: Remember who you are designing for.  If it's an internal piece of code a comment will suffice.  If it's a public API and you want people to inherit then you need to write a piece of documentation telling them to do it.  In C# you can do some sneaky stuff with virtual and non-virtual methods, but in Java it's a lot harder to enforce this without using an abstract base class.

Comment: @Spence You really understand my situation. I'm writing public API, so maybe comments or documents are not enough. Unfortunately, I can't find Java equivalence of `virtual` :( You should post your comment as answer, with some pieces of code, and I will choose your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it (C#):

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

    public void Run() {
        //code that will always run
        addToRunningVehicleList();

        //code that can be overriden
        RunImpl();
    }

    protected virtual void RunImpl() { }
}

public class Car : Vehicle {

    protected override void RunImpl() {
        carRunningAnimation();
    }

}
```

You can make the `RunImpl` protected to make sure it can't be called outside the subclasses of `Vehicle`.

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve this in Java? I can't find `virtual` equivalence in Java.

Comment: in Java all methods are virtual, unless you mark them final http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)

Comment: Thank you for your very interesting fact. But there is still a problem, just edited my question.

Comment: Actually your runImpl can be protected. I eddited my answer. This way it's not available outside of the subclasses of Vehicle. Also note that your run method should be final to avoid being overriden.

Comment: You don't understand my purpose. The `Vehicle` class is for PUBLIC, for end-user to create something like `Car` or whatever. In conclusion, this is what I need: Giving the `Vehicle` class, anyone can extends it and use `run` default method. Or they can override it if needed, but it MUST call `super.run()` method.

Comment: Well what you want exactly as described is not possible. However what I suggest is effectively the same. You put the stuff that always has to run in run() and the stuff that can be override in runImpl()

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is the best so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to require certain code to run in addition to the child class' implementation, perhaps you need to split this into multiple methods:

(C# example)

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public void Run()
    {
        // Code that always runs before...

        RunCore();

        // Code that always runs after...
    }

    protected virtual void RunCore()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember who you are designing for. If it's an internal piece of code a comment will suffice. If it's a public API and you want people to inherit then you need to write a piece of documentation telling them to do it.

In C# you can do some sneaky stuff with virtual and non-virtual methods but in Java as all inheritence is virtual it's a lot harder to enforce this without using an abstract base class.

Using an ABT may limit your ability to provide further inheritence and force modification of other code.